# Writing CR+LF into Open XML from a Database

Tags: ms-word, newline, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to take some data stored in a database and populate a Word template's Content Controls with it using the Open XML SDK. The data contains paragraphs and so there are carriage return and line feed characters in it. The data is stored in the database as `nvarchar`.

When I open the generated document, the `CR`+`LF` combination shows up as a question mark with a box around it (not sure the name of this character). This is actually two sequences back to back, so `CR`+`LF` `CR`+`LF` equals two strange characters:

[image: strange character]

If I unzip the `.docx`, take the Custom XML part and do a hex dump, I can clearly see `0d0a 0d0a` so the `CR`+`LF` is there. Word is just printing it weird.

I've tried enforcing UTF-8 encoding in my `XmlWriter`'s settings, but that didn't seem to help:

```vb
Dim docStream As New MemoryStream
Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings()
settings.Encoding = New UTF8Encoding(False)
Dim docWriter As XmlWriter = XmlTextWriter.Create(docStream, settings)
```

Does anyone know how I can get Word to render these characters correctly when written to a `.docx` through the Open XML SDK?

Comment: Perhaps helpful to understand that Word would not save CR/CRLF combinations but has XML constructs instead - e.g. a paragraph with "abc" then a line break, then "def" would be more like: <w:p><w:r><w:t>abc</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:br/></w:r><w:r><w:t>def</w:t></w:r></w:p>

Comment: Correct. @bibadia provided the answer. I use an add-in with Open XML editor to analyze what is happening. You can also debug from VS using an add-in you develop and look at the xml version continuously when stepping through.

Comment: @bibadia Okay, that is helpful. I can probably just run a regex replace over the string from the database to apply the proper tags. But I tried to add those tags in manually to the custom XML part and Word can no longer read the document. I included the `w` namespace from some MSDN articles but that didn't help. Any idea if these tags are different for custom XML parts?

Comment: My mistake - if the data is going in the custom part then it shouldn't have the XML encoding (unless you are going to open in Word 2013 and your control is a rich text control, in which case the Custom Part needs rather more).  I see 0d0a here for a line break in the control. I suppose it is possible that the control is not set to be multiline, but here the line breaks just disappear when displayed in that case.

Comment: @bibadia Well, I _am_ opening in Word 2013 and the control _is_ a rich text control. Could you please expand on what you mean by "rather more"? Possibly an MSDN link with the relevant information? Also, I see no option in the properties to set the control to be multiline. Where is that located?

Comment: Look for "Flat OPC" format. It's what you get if you save from Word 2013 as Word XML Document. It's possible that Word will let you use the simpler "Word 2003 XML Document" but you would need to check.

Answer (score 1):

To bind to a Word 2013 rich text control, your XML element has to contain a complete docx.  See [MS-DOCX]:

> the data stored in the XML element will be an escaped string comprised of a flattened WordprocessingML document representing the formatted data in the structured document tag range.

Earlier versions couldn't bind a rich text control.

Things should work though (with CR/LF, not w:br), if you bind to a plain text control, with multiline set to true.

Comment: It definitely needs to be a Rich Text control. The ability to format it is a requirement. Binding to a pre-formatted complete `.docx` would actually be beneficial. Though I con't figure out how to do so. I uploaded a Word XML file as suggested by @bibadia. I used LINQ to retrieve it from the database. I then tried to use my `XmlWriter` to write it to the appropriate element as a string. But what was populated was `System.Byte[]`. Any hints as to how I could write the complete `.docx` into the Custom XML part?

Comment: You can actually format a plain text control, via w:sdtPr/w:rPr, but only uniformly.

Comment: For flattened WordML, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/29/the-flat-opc-format.aspx

Comment: In you need pre-2013 binding of a complete docx, docx4j (Java) and www.nuget.org/packages/docx4j.NET/3.0.1 support that.